# Can you please help identify these fonts? I need to find them for a project

Tags: fonts, text, japanese

[image]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

What font is used in these graphics? I tried putting them through different font identifiers but I couldn't find it. probably wasn't in their catalogue. One of them appears to be hand-drawn

If anyone knows what fonts they are please answer here.

Both of these use the same font by the way.

[image]

Comment: Please stick to one font per question

Comment: You can use likefont.com to identify CJK fonts.

Comment: I'll edit this now to only stick to one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!! I found the font it's mikachan from this website it can be downloaded.
http://www.mia-lab.com/mf/